# gnuplot: create boxplot from raw data

Tags: gnuplot, boxplot

can gnuplot create a boxplot from a raw data file? I know how I can plot a boxplot from the already calculated median, quartiles and so on [like this](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.4/candlesticks.html) - but how from a raw data file?

In each line of the raw data file there is one test result.

Answer (score 2):

Just came across this myself, in the gnuplot 4.5 (cvs development version currently) it has this feature.

Currently that means you have to compile gnuplot yourself from the sources, http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/development/index.html#DownloadCVS.

Once you get that done, here's a demo file: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.5/boxplot.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to end up use external program to calculate the necessary data for box plot. I've used awk, but any program can be used in the place. Note that I've calculated opening/closing/minimum/maximum values in each line of raw data, instead of mean and quantiles.

```
set xrange [-1:9]
plot "< awk '{sum=0; opening=$1; closing=$NF; min=$1; max=$1; \
              for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {sum=sum+$i; if ($i<min) min=$i; if ($i>max) max=$i}; \
              print sum/NF, opening, closing, min, max}' \
        junk.dat" us 0:2:4:5:3 w candle notitle
```

With the following data in `junk.dat` file:

```
   5.532    5.040    4.962   19.314    5.136
  10.004    4.592    5.836    6.999    7.823
   8.887    6.335    5.545    5.056    6.216
   4.341    4.552    4.512    4.009    5.811
   4.724    4.869    5.016    2.593    5.662
   4.555    5.472    4.866    5.559   -0.608
   6.974    3.838    2.953    6.630    2.753
   5.571    8.112    3.261    7.029    4.375
   3.497    5.200    6.555    5.311    8.204
```

Here's the plot you will get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly and you are looking for a way to calculate the mean value you could do something like this:

```
calc_mean(x1,x2,x3) = (x1+x2+x3)/3
calc_sum(x1,x2,x3)  = x1+x2+x3
get_min(x1,x2,x3)   = x1 < x2 ? (x1 < x3 ? x1 : (x2 < x3 ? x2 : x3)) : (x2 < x3 ? x2 : x3)
get_max(x1,x2,x3)   = x1 > x2 ? (x1 > x3 ? x1 : (x2 > x3 ? x2 : x3)) : (x2 > x3 ? x2 : x3)

plot "Data.csv" u 0:(calc_mean($1, $2, $3)) t "Mean" w l, \
         "" u 0:(calc_sum($1, $2, $3)) t "Sum" w l, \
         "" u 0:(get_min($1, $2, $3)) t "Min" w l, \
         "" u 0:(get_max($1, $2, $3)) t "Max" w l
```

The script above calculates the mean, the sum, the minimum and the maximum value of a data line. The `0` in the using directive simply takes the index of the data line as the x-coordinate value.

With the following `Data.csv`:

```
0.62614   0.50293   0.62078
0.63789   0.58924   0.71288
0.16297   0.77453   0.82417
0.20703   0.22424   0.33596
0.57829   0.96545   0.60737
```

You will get the following plot:

[image: Plot of the script above]

I hope this is what you were looking for.